# PHP - MySQL query not working completely

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using `REPLACE INTO` query to update my database from array using `foreach`.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {

$outletid = $row['outletid'];
$loc = $row['loc'];
$coname = $row['coname'];
$addr1 = $row['addr1'];
$addr2 = $row['addr2'];
$addr3 = $row['addr3'];
$type1 = $row['type1'];
$type2 = $row['type2'];
$type3 = $row['type3'];
$type4 = $row['type4'];
$type5 = $row['type5'];
$mdate = $row['mdate'];

$sql = $conn->prepare("REPLACE INTO syscompany (outletid, loc, coname, addr1, addr2, addr3, type1, type2, type3, type4, type5, mdate)
                         VALUES ('$outletid', '$loc', '$coname', '$addr1', '$addr2', '$addr3', '$type1', '$type2', '$type3', '$type4', '$type5', '$mdate')");

$sql -> execute();
}
```

I have `147 rows` of records in my database. However, the query just don't work completely. I've tried to `delete 30 rows` and modify random rows from my database, and the query only insert back `5 rows` and updates about a few rows. I've tried to `print_r` all my variables `$outletid, $loc ...` and the values inside are all correct. I'm not sure how would it happen.
I've also tried to `echo` errors but nothing show up.

```
if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome? You haven't explained clearly. Do you understand how `REPLACE INTO` works, meaning is that what you really meant to use? You are preparing but are still passing values directly? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: That is not how prepared statements are meant to be written (parameterize!). Also where is this data coming from, maybe it can be done in 1 query..

Comment: @Script47 the expected outcome should be the absent row to be inserted, and present row deleted and insert again

Comment: @user3783243 coming from $data which is an array holds on the values

Comment: But did `$data` come from the DB already?

Comment: @user3783243 it comes from other DB

Comment: Ah, okay. If you output the query and execute it manually does it behave as expected?

Comment: @user3783243 yes , i tried the query in `phpadmin` and works fine , im not sure whether it has something to do with the `foreach`

Comment: Does it make it throw a certain number then die or what is the behavior? What is `$sql` when the behavior occurs (`var_dump($sql)`)?

Comment: and i'm not really understand what `prepare` works as, i'm just learning from websites

Comment: @user3783243 `var_dump` prints the correct value

Comment: Well that's a problem...it should only return a boolean. Prepared statements should have placeholders instead of the actual value. The query is always the same and should not be in the loop. The binding of the placeholder to the value should be in the loop and the the execute should occur in the loop. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#77107.

Comment: @user3783243 i don't really understand, could u gv advice on how i should modify my codes

Comment: `execute()` only returns `true` or `false` it shouldn't return a value to you.

Comment: @user3783243 then how should i run my query

Answer (score 0):

The pattern in the code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Best practice is to use bind placeholders, and provide values as bind values.

*static SQL text*

```
$sql = 'REPLACE INTO syscompany
        ( outletid, loc, coname
        , addr1, addr2, addr3
        , type1, type2, type3
        , type4, type5, mdate
        ) VALUES
        ( ?, ?, ?
        , ?, ?, ?
        , ?, ?, ?
        , ?, ?, ?
        )';
```

*prepare SQL text into a statement*

```
if(! $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
   // handle error
}
```

then we can process RBAR in a loop, executing the previously prepared statement ...

```
foreach( ... ) {
    ...   
    ... 

    // bind values and execute 
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssss'
        , $outletid, $loc, $coname
        , $addr1, $addr2, $addr3
        , $type1, $type2, $type3
        , $type4, $type5, $mdate);

    if(! $stmt->execute() ) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

---

We don't know if the table has a PRIMARY KEY or any UNIQUE indexes. We can only speculate. The behavior will depend that, and what rows already exist in the table.

The `REPLACE INTO` operates as a series of `DELETE` statements, followed by an `INSERT`.  Assuming `outletid` is the PRIMARY KEY of the table, and that `(coname,addr1)` is a UNIQUE KEY

The `REPLACE INTO` would be equivalent to running these two statements

```
 DELETE FROM syscompany WHERE outletid = ? ;
 DELETE FROM syscompany WHERE coname = ? and addr1 = ? ;
```

(with values supplied from the row to be inserted), followed by

```
 INSERT INTO syscompany ...
```